# Add row in a table and mantain formulas

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I would like add the last but one row in few tables and mantain formulas (copy the formula - for example in the row before - and past on the blank row). 
The first step (add the last but one row) doesn`t work. 
Someone can help me, please?

The code is:

```
`Sheet18.Activate
With Sheet18
last_row_with_data = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
last_row_with_data = last_row_with_data - 1
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Pessoal").ListRows.Add (last_row_with_data)
End With`
```

Comment: Is "Pessoal" on the ActiveSheet, or is it on Sheet18?  (Sheet18 is not necessarily the active sheet when you are executing the line which says `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Pessoal").ListRows.Add (last_row_with_data)`)  If it is on Sheet18 change `ActiveSheet.` to `.`.

Comment: "Pessoal" is on the Sheet18.

Comment: I`ve just changed but it doesn`t work too.

Comment: (a) What is the value of `last_row_with_data` when it crashes?  (b) Is `Sheet18` the sheet with the name "Sheet18" and, if not, is `Sheet18` the sheet you are really trying to access, or is `Worksheets("Sheet18")` the one you want?  (The sheet number and the sheet name are not necessarily linked - I often seem to end up with `Sheet1` having the name "Sheet2" and `Sheet2` having the name "Sheet1".)

Comment: Ok, it works. Thank you very much. And how can I mantain the formulas, as  the row before.

Comment: If "Pessoal" is an Excel table, I thought it automatically copied the formulas when you did a ListRows.Add.  But never having used Excel tables, I'm probably not the best person to assist in answering that question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
With Sheet18.ListObjects("Pessoal").ListRows
    .Add(.Count)
End With`
```

Comment: If `Sheet18` is a valid worksheet reference and _"Pessoal"_ is a valid name of a [ListObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197604.aspx) in that sheet then it _does_ work, i.e. it adds a new row just before _Pessoal_ table  last one. You may want to check it and let me know